# I'm Using Camick's ListTableModel and RowTableModel, NO DATA IN JTABLE

Tags: java, mysql, metadata, resultset

I am trying to use the ListTableModel and tried following some examples online and still finding it difficult to show 'resultSet' data in my Jtable. Im using the model-view-controller method building a GUI application in netbeans. All of my GUI components are placed in views and the controller is handling any updates as well visibility to this view. The model class has all the queries and is responsible for accessing the database directly using JDBC.

The "Jtable" "searchTable" is created and initialized inside the view class and is being accessed by my controller via a method (getSearchTable()).

```
public JTable getSearchTable(){
// view class
return searchTable;

}
```

I have the "ListTableModel" being created inside the controller class and following Camick's tutorial.

```
private Product_View productView;
private Product_Model productModel;
    private Product product;

public Product_Controller(Product_Model model, Product_View view){
    this.productModel = model;
    this.productView = view;

    view.addSaveListener(new SaveListener());
    view.addCloseListener(new CloseListener());
            view.addSearchSingleListener(new SearchListener());
}

public void displayProductView(){
    this.productView.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            this.productView.setVisible(true);
} class SearchListener implements ActionListener {

    public SearchListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        ListTableModel model = null;
        String prodName = productView.getProductName();
        JTable tempTable = productView.getSearchTable();

        model = productModel.getProduct(prodName, model);
        tempTable = new JTable(model);

    }
}
```

Finally the method "getProduct" is inside the model class and being called by my controller class.

```
public ListTableModel getProduct(String productName, ListTableModel model){
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE name='" + productName + "';";

    Statement stmt;

    try {
        stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeQuery (query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
                    writeResultSet(rs);
        model = ListTableModel.createModelFromResultSet(rs);  
        rs.close ();
        stmt.close ();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
    return model;
}
```

The Jtable does not return anything, how can i view my ResultSet data (i have printed out the values being returned by "writeResultSet" to the console and so the query is working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a table doesn't add the table to the GUI. Somewhere in your code you need code like:

```
frame.add( table );
```

If you are updating an existing table then you don't create a new table all you do is:

```
table.setModel(...);
```

after recreating the model.

Edit:

To test your SQL create a simple SSCCE with code something like:

```
ListTableModel model = ListTableModel.createModelFromResultSet( resultSet );
JTable table = new JTable( model );
frame.add( new JScrollPane( table ) );
frame.setSize(...);
frame.setVisible( true );
```

Comment: First of all thanks. After setting the table's model using the suggested method i am now able to get the correct column names in my Jtable but still no data in the Jtable?

Comment: @Warz, I would guess your writeResultSet() method reads through the ResultSet so when you invoke the createModelFromResultSet() method, there is no more data to read. Get rid of that method call. If you want to see what data is in the model then iterate through the model using the getValueAt(...) method after invoking the createModelFrom...() method.

Comment: mhmm, i have commented out that particular method and printed out separately what each column would return but still no data in the Jtable, could it be because of the way i am referencing it?

Comment: @Warz, I don't know why you would get heading but no data. There must be something with your MVC design which I can't help you out with. So you need to step back to make sure you understand the basics of using this code. Create a simple SSCCE that executes your SQL and builds a table. The basic code is included in my update.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I know at least understand that i was referencing the wrong table and will look back at my code.